# open multiple shell in one serial redirected console in linux

Tags: linux, shell, serial-port

As we can open multiple shell sessions in one Terminal by ctrl+shift+t.  Is there any way to open multiple shell in a single serially redirected console?

I have redirected the console over serial  `ttys0` by making changes in `/etc/inittab` and connected to COMPORT of another PC through hyper terminal.  After booting and login through root over serially redirected console displaying on hyper terminal, I want to start new shell on that keeping old one safe. and want to switch between those shells.

Actually I am running APP on first shell, and want to use other shell for Linux commands, to be executed whenever I need, without quitting from my first APP.

What can be the possible way?

Comment: use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)?

Comment: screen is good. byobu (https://launchpad.net/byobu/) is better (actually, it's just some custom config files and wrappers for screen). Anyways, it should get the work done!